# i2C HID touchpad problem

Tags: mouse, touchpad

**i2c_hid_acpi: probe of i2c-DELL0A23:00 failed with error -110**

So this is a problem I faced in windows as well. I know my touchpad will work if i Uninstall or disable i2c HID but I don't know how to in windows. Please help.

I found this by the following commands;

sudo journalctl -b

/input

Under;
PS/2 Generic Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
error-i2c_hid_acpi: probe of i2c-DELL0A23:00 failed with error -110

Comment: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-Developer-Systems/i2c-hid-i2c-DELL0831-00-i2c-hid-get-input/td-p/6219894

Comment: I think I will have to remove this i2c driver. is there a way to fully remove it or disable it somehow?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I think my p.c. is downloading this extra driver which is causing the problem. What happens is that if I download a new os or if i re-install windows this driver doesn't start and so my touch-pad wont work at all. But when I disable this it fixes automatically. I think this is because I already have another driver, I can be totally wrong, this just as much I can figure out. And Btw thanks the problem is solved.